# How can I import local font in Reactjs with Styled Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";

createGlobalStyle`
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Segoe Pro Regular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url('SegoePro-Regular.woff') format('woff');
}`
```

After that I add `import "./components/GlobalStyles";` to index.js

I tried to use it in some component with `font-family: Segoe Pro Regular;` but it's not working

---

I also tried with importing

```
import Font from "./SegoePro-Regular.woff"
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";

    createGlobalStyle`
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'Segoe Pro Regular';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        src: url(${Font}) format('woff');
    }`
```

Comment: Do you use webpack or cra ?

Comment: Create-react-app which using webpack

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`font-family: Segoe Pro Regular;` isn't a valid syntax, you should try:

```
font-family: 'Segoe Pro Regular';
```

Here is a working example for reference:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';
import MajorMonoTTF from './MajorMonoDisplay-Regular.ttf';

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Major Mono Display';
    src: url(${MajorMonoTTF}) format('truetype');
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: auto;
  }
  h1 {
    font-family: 'Major Mono Display';
  }
`;

const App = () => (
  <>
    <GlobalStyle />
    <h1>Cool Title</h1>
  </>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[image: Edit Q-58787035-FontFamily]

Comment: I tried import with `"@fonts/SegoePro/SegoePro-Black.woff"` but React says "module not found"

Comment: Its an alias... you can't use @ font

Comment: I added a sandbox example, also your codepen is `404`